# Angular: Help on in-place editable form

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to create an in-place editable form, whose controls at once should toggle between editable and view-only modes on click of a button outside (I don't want individual controls to be clicked in order to toggle edit mode).

I've created this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z9gkdu) where I'm getting an error saying, `No provider for NgControl`. I don't want to wrap form elements over each of the editable control components that I'm looking to create. Please help me with this.

My intended control is something like,
`<editable-control [mode]="formMode" type="text"></editable-control>`

Answer (score 2):

Your custom form component implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, therefore it needs the `NgControl` provider. You have to use the `ReactiveFormsModule` instead of the `FormsModule`.

So you have to import it from `@angular/forms` and add it to the imports array of the corresponding NgModule:

```
// ...
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     // ...
     ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
// ...
```

To use you custom component you can use it together with `formGroup` directive. For example:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <editable-control [mode]="formMode" type="text" formControlName="myText">
  </editable-control>
</form>
```

Comment: How to provide it?

Comment: That worked... Now it shows another error saying, `formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.`, but I don't want to wrap a `formGroup` inside that component, as I wanna do it from the component that consumes it. Any workaround for it?

Comment: Now I used `ngModel` instead of `formControlName` inside the component and it worked!

Comment: Ah you mean the input element inside your custom component, didn't get that. But yeah using `ngModel` inside your custom component is the right way.